# Angular 2 “ng-style” within “*ngFor” background color change

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, angular, ionic2

I am trying to apply background colors using `ng-style`. Each row of list is generated using `ngFor`. Each item having separate background colors

```
<ion-item class="category-list" *ngFor="let item of character['items']">
   <ion-avatar item-left>
  <i class="icon" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item.bgcolor}"><img src="../img/icons/category/{{item.img}}.png"></i>
  </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{item.category}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
```

And the Typescript.ts:

```
 var characters = [
  {
    name: 'Gollum',
    quote: 'Sneaky little hobbitses!',
   items: [
      { bgcolor: 'fb9667', img: 'airTicket', category: 'Air tickets' },
      { bgcolor: '000000', img: 'airTicket', category: 'Beauty/Fitness'},
      { bgcolor: '0b9660', img: 'airTicket', category: 'Bike'}
    ]
  },
]
```

Don't know how to apply color code to list.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change the background colour using `[style.backgroundColor]`:

```
<i class="icon" [style.backgroundColor]="item.bgcolor"></i>
```

If of course the string in `item.bgcolor` is a valid css colour string:

`#FFFFFF`
`white`
`rgb(255,255,255)`
`rgba(255,255,255,1)`

Which in your case isn't.. You are missing the leading `#` and you should change your item list to this:

```
items: [
      { bgcolor: '#fb9667', img: 'airTicket', category: 'Air tickets' },
      { bgcolor: '#000000', img: 'airTicket', category: 'Beauty/Fitness'},
      { bgcolor: '#0b9660', img: 'airTicket', category: 'Bike'}
]
```

Comment: its not working.. its need to add # tag in front of this ?

Comment: that's what i said.. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can directly apply this css and the alternate rows will have different color

li { background: green; }

li:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }

Comment: i need each row different color its more than 50 rows

Answer (score 1):

for future reference for other developers, here's my answer.
the function will loop all the colors to each row the `ngFor` will generate

```
<ion-col [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColors(i) }" *ngFor="let data of Data;let i = index">
```

```
Colors:Array<any> = ["#FFF","#0b9660","#FF0000","#000","#FFF","#ffd11a","#fb9667"];

  getColors(index) {

    let num = this.getnumber(index);
    return this.Colors[num];
  }

  getnumber(data){

    let i = data;
    if(i > this.Colors.length-1){

       i = i - this.Colors.length;
       if(i < this.Colors.length){
        return i;
       }
       else {
        this.getnumber(i);
       }

    }
    else {
      return i;
    }


  }
```